# Cannot fetch an array within an object with axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

see the code below:

```
//useState to store the file data:
const [gotData, setData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    //calling the file's data. 
    instance(`/${filename.replace(" ", "%20")}`)
    .then(res => setData(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
},[filename]);

return(
    <div className="__te_onlineBanking__Form">
        <form>
            {gotData.formInputFields.map(elem => {return(
            <span>
                <label htmlFor= {elem.id}>{elem.labelText}</label>
                <input type= {elem.inputType} required id = {elem.id} placeholder = {elem.placeholder} name = {elem.name}/>
            </span>)
            })}
        </form>
        {console.log(gotData.formInputFields)}
        <button onClick = {close}>Submit</button>
    </div>
)
```

The problem occurs in the **map function**. Right now in the above code, I am storing the data directly into the state variable with **setData(res.data)**, FYI, res.data is an object with some properties and an array for the form input field names. So, when I try to write, **gotData.formInputFields.map()**, I get an error saying cannot read property, map of undefined. However when I set **setData(res.data.formInputFields)**, and then call **gotData.map()**, the problem is **solved**. But, **I dont want to use two separate useStates** for storing the form input field data and other information that I might need. **I just want to setData(res.data) and call the map with gotData.formInputFields.map()**. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not confused, your problem is that `gotData` is an object or JSON, so the first iteration is `gotData.formInputFields.map` but `formInputFields` do not exist, as you wrote `useState({})` so the initial state is `gotData = {}`.

Remember that you will have data on `gotData` once you have a response on your AJAX call, and that will take more time than the first render.

I recommend you to write `useState({ formInputFields: [] })` or change your return from `{gotData.formInputFields.map(elem => {return(` to `{gotData?.formInputFields?.map(elem => {return(` or `{gotData && gotData.formInputFields && gotData.formInputFields.map(elem => {return(`

Comment: Thank you so much. Totally solved my problem, I never knew that var? was a thing. Learned a new thing today. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad this solved your issue. Using `?.` is called optional chaining and is a "new" thing in JS

Answer (score 0):

Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
gotData.formInputFields?.map(...)
```

This will check first if the attribute `formInputFields` exist in `gotData` before calling the `map` method